# Keras Squential Returning Table Not Initialized Error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to compare cosine similarities and euclidean distances of different pairs of sentence vectors, embedded by some text embedding module provided from tensorflow hub. I made a Keras Sequential model, and added the embedding layer to it, so that the 'prediction' or 'evaluation' of input texts would be their embedded vectors.

The exact same code worked fine two days ago, but it started to return "Failed precondition: Table not initialized." error when calling 'predict' on vectorizor. When it worked, I didn't even set "steps=1" inside predict but it worked fine. Now, I had to because with it the code returns "ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model, you should specify the `steps` argument."

Why would the code that worked well two days ago suddenly started to return errors?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Dense, Dot, Input
import tensorflow_hub as hub


vectorizer = Sequential()

embed_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-ko-dim128-with-normalization/1", output_shape=[128],
                             input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string)

vectorizer.add(embed_layer)
```

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances


string = "I like you"
str_tensor = tf.constant(string, shape = [1], dtype=tf.string)

string2 = "I hate you"
str_tensor2 = tf.constant(string2, shape = [1], dtype=tf.string)

print(vectorizer)


a = vectorizer.predict(str_tensor, steps=1)
b = vectorizer.predict(str_tensor2)

cos_sim = cosine_similarity(a, b)
euc_dis = euclidean_distances(a, b)

print(cos_sim)
print(euc_dis)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to tensorflow 2.0 and worked fine...